# Android Sqlite how to use one table out of the two created?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am on Android and this question is of Sqlite :

I have a table (`USERLOGIN`) which holds the user's credentials (username and password) in it.  I have another table (`$USER$_PROJS`) which holds information of projects for a particular user. Users can create and add projects in there.

[ `$USER$` will be a variable which comes from the column `username` in `USERLOGIN` table. So its basically a dynamic table creation. ]

Both of these tables are in the same database USER.db.
I have only one `LoginDatabseAdapter` class and `DatabseHelper` class which manages both of these.

Now initially when user logs-in, the database is behaving properly. But when inside the user profile when a user tries to create/add project its not inserting the values into `$USER$_PROJS` table.

I think i need to use the `USE TABLE` (once the user successfully logs-in his profile) like statement but its giving an error when i try to use it.

I have searched almost all the resources on net but was unable to find the solution !!
Any help would be appreciated !!

CODE RESPONSIBLE FOR CREATING TABLE :

```
public void createprojtable(String u){
        db.execSQL(
"create table if not exists "+u+"_PROJS(ID integer primary key autoincrement,
        PROJ_NAME text,DATE text); ");
    }

    public void insertProjEntry(String u,String projName,
            String projdate) {
        //db.execSQL("use table "+u+"_PROJS;");
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put("PROJ", projName);
        newValues.put("DATE", projdate);
        db.insert(u+"_PROJS", null, newValues);
    }
```

Comment: Ok. So what do you mean by Dynamic table creation. Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: dynamic table creation >> creating table on the fly >>>
creating table on the fly >> creating table from the user input !!
any need of 'dynamic table creation' needs some explaination in this question !! ??

Comment: So for every user will there be a project table ?

Comment: I would suggest you to create a table USER which will contain userid as primary key , username and password . And the instead of creating multiple PROJECT tables for each user , create only one PROJECT table having projectid as primary key , project name and date along with one more column userid as foreign key that references userid of USER table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Cursors for Sqlite in Android. You get Cursors specific to a table. Using the Cursors you can read data from a specific table as such. While updating the data also you can specify table name as one of the parameters. So you can pretty much get what you are looking for using existing APIs.

Have a look at following links :

1. [Android SQLite Database and ContentProvider - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
2. [android.database.sqlite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html)

Comment: okay so i need to use cursor to change my currently selected table.
For once its fine but what if need to regularly do it ,then should i update/declare the cursor at the start of every function ??

Comment: I will suggest reading this for performance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875774/how-do-i-achieve-best-performance-using-sqlite-in-android

Comment: you are not getting what i am asking.
The link you have given is for a single table example.The author never uses two tables.
Though we can derive that cursor may be able to solve my prob but is it the only thing that will be able to solve it ?
I think the sqlite guys must have given this condition a thought and might have given the solution too and it might be the cursor.but who knows..
An exact answer or approach is more acceptable !!
and if this is right it will have its 'right' !!